# Implement switch for flutter in realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help in creating buttons for realtime database in my flutter app. I'm a newbie to flutter and I'm finding it hard to implement this

Comment: You will see people volunteer to help you solve a problem in Stackoverflow. But as for someone to teach you in full, it is tough. If you are new to Flutter, learn Flutter well from the abundance of Flutter resources out there. Learn Firebase too. If you understand how these technologies work. You won't ask this question. Besides, the question is ambiguous or vague. Also, you need to provide an attempt before someone can help you from a point.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.